# Canopy python 32 bit Mac os x

Tags: python, macos, 32-bit, canopy

ive been having trouble using a 32 bit python for canopy on mac. I dont know how to import a external version of python. Ive tried sites, but they all are from 2013-14. They just say to download the v1 with 32 bit python. I want any version of python that is 32 bit to work with canopy, I hope someone knows how, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Canopy on Mac has not provided 32-bit Python since January 2015.

If you've got a really old (32-bit) version of OSX, then you're out of luck. Otherwise (you've got a recent OSX but just want to run 32-bit Python for some reason (WHY?) then...

I'm not clear from your question whether you have a 32-bit / IPython available. If so, then from a terminal where that is your default Python, you can start a 32-bit kernel with `ipython kernel`.

If that version of Ipython is not too old (sorry, not sure what exactly that means), then you should then be able to connect to that kernel from Canopy's Run menu ("Connect to existing kernel"). Not super convenient, as you'd need to redo both steps every time you wanted to do this.